# Как правильно разобрать Json?

Tags: php, ajax, json

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста! Собираю данные из бд и формирую ассоциативный массив.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("test_basa");
$o = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_table");
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($o)) {
         $arr[] = array($result['name'], $result['date'], $result['que']);

    }
    //var_dump($arr);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Далее, на стороне клиента делаю ajax-запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax_que.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data_db) {
        var answer = JSON.parse(data_db);
        console.log(data_db);
    }

});
```

Выходит ошибка: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Я так понимаю, это потому что мы получаем объект.

Мне же необходимо получить из вышеприведенного php-файла ассоциативный массив, чтобы потом его в том же виде можно было использовать в javascript.
То есть формируется, например, в php: [['one', 'two'], ['ten', 'eleven']], и в таком же виде мне нужен этот массив в javascript :)
Как это сделать?

Comment: вы уже получаете распарсеный json. так что юзайте сразу без `JSON.parse` просто `data_db`

Comment: @Naumov То есть в answer уже лежит ассоциативный массив, или же его нужно преобразовать?

Answer (score 0):

т.к. в `dataType` ajax запроса указано, что он ожидает с сервера ответ в виде `json`, то функция попытается автоматически распарсить эту строку в нужный объект.

С сервера видно, что отсылается json.

Поэтому в переменной `data_db` **ужЕ** будет нужная структура и дополнительно применять парсинг не нужно.

Поэтому и `JSON.parse` ругается, что он не может распарситьтекущий ответ, потому что он ожидал бы json-строку, а в итоге получил json-объект.